# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'

Tags: python

I had an Import err that says `"No module named util"`, but i cant find any package named `util`.
what path should I append in?

Code from LSTNet tensorflow by fabdline.
https://github.com/fbadine/LSTNet

```
# Path appended in order to import from util
import sys
#sys.path.append("..")
sys.path.append('../')  #？what path should I Append?

import os

from util.model_util import LoadModel, SaveModel, SaveResults, SaveHistory
from util.Msglog import LogInit
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 19, in
>   
>       from util.model_util import LoadModel, SaveModel, SaveResults, SaveHistory ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'

Comment: So carelessly. Alright. It's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the install instructions from the link you posted.

Under [Installation](https://github.com/fbadine/LSTNet#installation) it's stated:

> Clone this prerequisite repository:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/fbadine/util.git
> ```

All the files you need can be found at https://github.com/fbadine/util

Comment: Alright. I just download the LSTnet files and run it at windows. Thanks Bro.